# While statement in assembly programming keil u-version4

Tags: assembly, arm

i want to translate this upcode in assembler programming keil uversion 4:

```
n = 5,
fac = 1,
next = 2

while  next <= n do

   fact = fact * next
   next = next + 1``

end
```

thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Keil uses an ARM CPU, as far as I know. The basic sequence would go:

```
mov r0, #5 ;n
mov r1, #1 ;fact
mov r2, #2 ;next
b LoopCheck

Loop:
mul r1, r1, r2
add r2, r2, #1

LoopCheck:
cmp r2, r0
ble Loop
```

Your assembler's syntax might vary. Also, the hardware/OS might prefer the Thumb instruction set; I won't know about that.

Your snippet omits the hairiest details of all - how do you get the input values and what do you do with the result. The algorithm is pure vanilla ARM, independent of the particulars of the platform; I/O won't be.